# OCUnit: How to run tests without launching iPhone simulator?

Tags: unit-testing, xcode4, ocunit

I'm following [iOS Development Guide: Unit Testing Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html). However, when I attempt to build (Command+B) the `LogicTests` target (step 8 of "Setting Up Logic Testing"), I get the error: "The selected run destination is not valid for this action."

Since I added my application target to `LogicTests`'s target dependencies, I'm able to run the unit tests with Command+U, but this also launches the iPhone Simulator.

To save time & resources, is it possible to run the OCUnit tests (both logic & application tests) without launching the iPhone Simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How much time/resources? Rather than focusing on reducing those, I'd focus on expanding your tests to go far beyond Apple's original "Logic Test" guidelines. Those guidelines were limiting, and written before Xcode 4. Now you can write tests without thinking, "Is this a logic test or an application test?" -- just test everything.

Comment: You say, "Now you can write tests without thinking, 'Is this a logic test or an application test?'" How & why? I.e., why would I not want to separate [acceptance tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_testing) from [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)?

Comment: What Apple has called "application tests" are not the same as acceptance tests. My unit tests verify my view controllers, as isolated units. For example: Populate model (possibly a fake). Instantiate view controller with model and invoke -load to simulate the view being loaded. Verify that views reflect model. This is a unit test, not an acceptance test. …The Apple document you reference is outdated, and doesn't apply to Xcode 4 testing.

Comment: OK, so then, I've updated my question: "Is it possible to run the OCUnit tests (both logic & application tests) without launching the iPhone Simulator?"

Comment: Agreed that the Apple documentation is out of date on this issue but this doesn't really answer the original question. It drives me crazy that running "Test" in Xcode 4 launches the simulator. It doesn't seem necessary at all.

Comment: Woo, -2 so far! It seems my attempt to help by steering people away from the starting point, "I'm following Unit Testing Applications," is not in vogue. To test things like notifications, connections, and views, iOS needs to be running. So let me offer a shorter answer: No.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the simulator popping up but I don't like the app delegate being triggered which then cascades a number of things I don't want happening in a test.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing True. So I avoid that by setting an environment variable when running tests. App delegate methods check for that variable and short-circuit if it's set.

Comment: @JonReid perfect. I just added an environment variable in the launch config for the tests and in the app delegate I launch a different dummy home screen. Works perfectly

Comment: @JonReid the short answer is incorrect. It is perfectly possible to run without launching the simulator. I was looking for a better way to do it than the one I know, but... Also, I have 5+ libraries driving my app, most libraries do not require the simulator so why would I want it popping up every-time I build any of them, I wonder?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale - how does the above answer get a tick? How does it answer your question???

Answer (score 8):

I understand the annoyance of the simulator popping up in unit tests.  The best remedy I've been able to find is to do Command + U, followed by Command + H when launching unit tests.  (Control + H hides the simulator after it appears.)  Since it appears nearly instantaneously, this can be an effective way of getting it out of your range of vision.

Comment: Really annoying when using full screen as it jumps you to the desktop. :(

Comment: @ChrisWagner +NSUIntegerMax!

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to run my unit tests which test my model classes without the simulator being launched as follows:

1. I didn't set any bundle loader or test host build settings, instead I just added the .m files I was unit testing to the Build Phases Compile Sources.
2. I then ran the unit tests from the command line using:

   ```
   xcodebuild -verbose -target TheElementsUnitTests -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator5.0 clean build
   ```

Not really sure why this didn't launch the simulator, but it definitely didn't!

Comment: This is what I use when doing continuous integration with Jenkins. Seems like a good way to run the tests and verify they all pass. I have not found a way to do the same from XCode UI without launching the Simulator, though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a small AppleScript that I set to run for *Generates output* in *Testing* behaviour configuration:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
activate application "Xcode"
```

It brings Xcode back immediately after pressing *command* + *U*.

P.S. I also opened a bug and Apple marked it as a duplicate. So, they're aware.